# How to send an id number into the Jquery modal form when editing a field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am a newbie in Jquery. I just wanna ask on how to send an id number into this code: `dlg.load('view.php?BookID=<?php echo $test['BookID'];?>', function()`. This is very usefull when we want to edit using Jquery modal form but it doesn't get the id number therefor I cannot edit the form.

My Jquery Code:

```
$('.edit').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         dlg.load('view.php?BookID=<?php echo $test['BookID'];?>', function(){ //i cannot get the BookID number
             dlg.dialog('open');
         });
     });
```

My php table code:

```
<table border="1">
    <?php
        include("db.php");

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books");

    while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

        $id = $test['BookID'];
    ?>

        <tr align='center'> 
        <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['BookID'];?></font></td>
        <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['Title'];?></font></td>
        <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['Author'];?></font></td>
        <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['PublisherName'];?></font></td>
        <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['CopyrightYear'];?></font></td>    
        <td><a class="edit" href='view.php?BookID=<?php echo $test['BookID'];?>' title="Edit">Edit</a> <!----for editing --->
        <div id="register" ></div>
        <td><a href ='del.php?BookID=<?php echo $test['BookID'];?>' title="Delete"><center>Delete</center></a>  
        </tr>

        <?php
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the information in the `href` attribute, so you can just get the URL from there, using the `attr` method:

```
$('.edit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dlg.load($(this).attr('href'), function(){
        dlg.dialog('open');
    });
});
```

The way it works:

First of all, jQuery will provide the context, setting the **this** object to the element on which the event is triggered, i.e. the `a` element.

Then, the `href` attribute value can be retrieved via the *attr* method. It will return whatever value is in that HTML attribute.

As PHP had already injected the URL in that attribute, it is readily available at the time of the click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your ID in a hidden input or data-attribute. Let's use the latter.

```
<tr align='center' data-book-id="<?php echo $test['BookID'] ?>">
```

In your jQuery code, get the ID

```
$('.edit').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // look for the row element that the link belongs to and get the 
     // the value of its data-book-id attribute
     var bookId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-book-id');
     // etc
});
```